# Why can't I initialize a variable using size() of a procedure argument in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, initialization

My question is why the following is allowed:

```
integer, intent(in) :: x(:)
integer :: dx(size(x))
```

while this is not:

```
integer, intent(in) :: x(:)
integer :: max_size = size(x)
```

(let alone defining max_size as a parameter).

I can wrap my head around why a value unknown for the compiler (i.e., size(x)) might be problematic to be used for initialization, but using an unknown value to define array size is much much worse! How come one is allowed bu not the other? Why size() cannot be used for initialization in Fortran?

Comment: Initialization in Fortran only happens at compile time (or program start). There is no specific `x` at the program start. I think we must have a duplicate. Next time, please show more code (see [mcve]). Fortunately, here the `intent(in)` reveals the problem.

Comment: You should also always include the error message ([ask]). It should have mentioned the nature of a problem even if in some unclear terms.

Comment: The linked question and its answers talk about named constants: the same arguments hold for explicit initialization. `dx(size(c))` is allowed as an automatic object and it's simply the initialization that is not allowed. `integer max_size;  max_size=size(x)` would be perfectly acceptable